# ExpressionEngine CP pages always seem to cache

Tags: control-panel, cache

I'm helping run an EE site that's developed a really strange problem that my other EE installs seem to have, even if they are on the same webhost and reseller hosting account.

What's going on is that control panel pages seem to keep getting cached. You'll do an action, and it will clearly be successful (you'll still get the green checkmark) but the reloaded page will be unchanged. Then you'll do a hard refresh on the page, and you'll definitely see it changed. Sometimes this problem is stubborn though, and you'll have to hard reload. This makes it difficult to change almost anything in the CP, like turning add-ons on and off, updating entries, etc.

I feel like this is either a very worrisome problem on a specific EE install, or a trivial issue I can change by updating a setting. Does anyone know why my site might be doing this? Interestingly, the front end of the site is not affected at all.

It sounds like it might be related to this issue but there were no answers suggested.

This site has existed since it was EE1 and went through an EE2 update.

Things I've done:

- cleared all caches in Tools > Data > Clear Cache

— checked that cache folder and subfolder are set to 777

- made sure no template uses Template Caching (even though those are front facing)

I'm running EE 2.9.2 and don't have any exotic caching plugins enabled, though I use Solspace Template Morsels.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EE Control Panel is never being cached by ExpressionEngine itself.
The chances are:

1. It is cached server-side by third-party server tools (you might want to talk to your hoster about that)
2. It is cached by your ISP, if you use proxy server
3. It is your browser's cache

As one possible way around, try changing Control Panel Session Type in preferences to different setting.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I also discovered some filetype caching tags in the htaccess (ExpiresByType) I put there a while ago to try to speed things up. On removing them, things seemed to get a little bit better and I didn't have to hard refresh every page in the CP, though some updates seemed to lag still. 

I'm not working on the site today or tomorrow, but some colleagues are, and I'll ask them for a report when I return.

Comment: Definitely, remove everything from the htaccess file, except the bare minimum, and test the control panel again. The ExpiresByType code caused issues in my EE control panel.